# About switching of language in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using a react dashboard and I wish to translate the app using i18next, I'm very beginner in React, I have a button to switch language like this :

```
                    <button className={`${styles.control} h5`} onClick={toggleDirection}>
                    <i className="icon icon-book-regular"/>
                    {direction === 'ltr' ? 'ENGLISH' : 'ARABIC'}
                   </button>
```

I wish to change the button without changing the style and button and doing something like that:

```
      import { Suspense, useState } from 'react';
      import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

      const locales = {
      en: { title: 'English' },
      es: { title: 'Arabic' },
      };

   const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
   <ul>
    {Object.keys(locales).map((locale) => (
      <li key={locale}><button style={{ fontWeight: i18n.resolvedLanguage === locale ? 'bold' : 'normal' }} type="submit" onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage(locale)}>
        {locales[locale].title}
      </button></li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear about what are you trying to accomplish but assuming that the `i18next` is configured and setup correctly, you can do the following

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

export default function Header() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation("global")

  return (
    <div>
      {t("header.chooseLanguage")}
      <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage("en")}>EN</button>
      <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage("es")}>ES</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

More details about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-multilingual-react-apps-with-react-i18next)